# Is it possible to get custom background around Text flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, instagram

I want a background like instagram stories/tiktok videos around the text. With custom borderradius and color. But when i see there is only a option background color on text. But that gives this result:
[image]

I want this result:

[image]

If is use richText with WidgetSpan i get this:

[image]

But i want that it wraps around the text and not that the container is a box

This is the code for the last screenshot:

```
 child: RichText(
text: WidgetSpan(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      color: Colors.blueAccent
    ),
    child: Text(
      providerItems.textItems[id].text + ' | ' + providerItems.textItems[id].id.toString(),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 26,
        //backgroundColor: Colors.blue
      ),
    ),
  )
),
```

),

Comment: Can you post some code to demonstrate how the text ist being built?

Comment: @kazume i posted the code

Comment: Seems to me that to get that effect, you'll have to build something yourself - at least I'm not aware of any widget that can give you this exact effect. Thinking CustomMultiChildLayout or something.

Answer (score 1):

This might helps:

You can set background as like below:

```
TextStyle(
 fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
 fontSize: 10,
 background: Paint()
       ..strokeWidth = 12
       ..color = Colors.grey
       ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
       ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
),
```

But if you decrease `strokeWidth` then you will have white space at inside area as it is width of outer stroke.